# How to get the List of ids from multiple ul tags using python?

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, automation

Here I want to get all the ids marked in red box in the given pic, in a list using python. This ids are random and dynamic too!

[image]

Comment: can you show what you have tried

Comment: what do you mean with "keep changing"?

Comment: Add a sample of that HTML or the page you are retrieving this from

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can serach the `ul` tag and loop through the search then get the attribute of the element.

```
elements=driver.find_elements_by_css_selector("ul.plan-card-blue")
id_list=[]
for ele in elements:
    id_list.append(ele.get_attribute("id"))
```

Answer (score 0):

extract all ul items from browser

```
   links = browser.find_elements_by_tag_name("ul")
```

loop the list and get id value

```
  for element in links
         idValue = element.get_attribute("id")
```

want to save it in an array use this

```
 idValue=[]
  for element in links:
         idValue.append(element.get_attribute("id"))
```

Comment: its works too, but also comes with some unnecessary items in the list. to eleminate those, the code should be:

for element in links:
     #as the ids are length of five, so its only get those.
     if len(element.get_attribute("id"))==5:
         idValue.append(element.get_attribute("id"))